# Momentjs returns date in wrong timezone

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, vuejs2

I'm having a problem with momentjs. I'm trying to generate all days from a specific month by using the `startOf` and `endOf` methods on my moment object like this:

`moment('2017-07-17').startOf('month')`

However, when I log the return value in the console it returns `"2017-06-30T22:00:00.000Z"`.
I expect it to just be `"2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"`.

I am using vue 2.x if that makes any difference, and I'm importing moment like `import moment from 'moment';`.

Comment: Z means that the date is displayed in UTC

Comment: Try `moment.utc(2017-07-17)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of timezone `moment('2017-07-17')` will take your local timezone which looks to be CEST.

instead do

`moment.utc('2017-07-17')`